# Sequence $a_n = (-1)^n\frac{n}{n+1}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that $a_n = (-1)^n\frac{n}{n+1}$ diverges.

My proof: We begin with arbitrary real number $A$ and prove that $\lim a_n$ does not equal $A$. Let us work with an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ and let $\epsilon = 1$. We need to show that for all $n$ in the naturals there exists a $m\ge n$ such that $|a_m - A| \ge \epsilon$. If we have $m\ge  1/|A| - 1$ then we have $|a_m - A| \ge 1$. We need to choose $m\ge \max\{1/|A|-1, n\}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Check the limit superior and limit inferior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sequence converged,
then,
for any $\epsilon > 0$,
there is a $N(\epsilon)$
such that
$|a_n -L| < \epsilon$
for
$n > N(\epsilon)$.

Note that
$a_{2n} \to 1$
and
$a_{2n+1} \to -1$.

If we choose $\epsilon < \frac12$,
we can show that
both
$|a_{2n}-L|<\epsilon$
and
$|a_{2n+1}-L|<\epsilon$
will lead to a contradiction
for large enough $n$.

Therefore
the sequence does not converge.

Personally,
I like to say that
this sequence
"multi-converges"
since it has
more than one limit point.
These sequences have interesting properties.

Answer (score 1):

If we take two subsequence $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$ , then both will converge to different limit . And all subsequence of a convergent sequence converge to same limit . Hence it is not a convergent sequence

Comment: @Bondoo7 I want to prove this using the definition of divergence (negation of convergence definition using epsilons)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is noting that the sequence is not Cauchy, $$|a_{n+1} - a_{n}| = \frac{2n}{n+1} \geq 1$$

Since all convergent sequences are Cauchy, the sequence $a_n$ does not converge.